# How to keep the page in Portrait mode in Windows Universal Apps?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am migrating my Windows Phone App to Windows Universal Apps. In my phone app, there was an attribute **Support Orientation** for which we can set value Portrait and Landscape.I want to achieve the same in Windows 8.1 App of Universal Apps. Even if the person rotated his/her tablet in landscape mode, my app should not get Rotated.

Please help me how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the AutoRotationPreferences property in the DisplayInformation class.

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
```

You should only need to set this property once in your application.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. If I add this in App.xaml.cs code then will it get reflected in entire app?

Comment: Yes, you can find a more detailed explanation of how this works [here](http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/2013/09/05/locking-orientation-supported-rotations-manifest/)